# Shopee affiliate open API return "Invalid Signature"

Tags: python, shopee

I have this code to get a list of items from shopee affiliate program. The code is quite straight forward.

```
import requests
import time
import hashlib

appID = APP_ID
secret = SECRET

# Set the API endpoint URL
url = "https://open-api.affiliate.shopee.com.my/graphql"

# Set the GraphQL query
body = """
{
  productOfferV2(
    listType:0
    sortType:5
  ) {
    nodes {
      commissionRate
      commission
      price
      productLink
      offerLink
    }
  }
}
"""
payload = {"query": body}

timestamp = str(int(time.time()))
factor = f'{appID}{timestamp}{payload}{secret}'
signature = hashlib.sha256(factor.encode()).hexdigest()


print(factor)

# Set the request headers
headers = {
    'Content-type':'application/json',
    'Authorization':f'SHA256 Credential={appID},Timestamp={timestamp},Signature={signature}'
}

# Send the POST request
response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

# Print the response
print(response.json())
```

after run I get this error

```
{'errors': [{'message': 'error [10020]: Invalid Signature', 'extensions': {'code': 10020, 'message': 'Invalid Signature'}}]}
```

I follow this:

https://ibb.co/q9JRB7h
https://ibb.co/th99m4F

I already check the `credential` and `timestamp` is correct. The only thing left is the `signature` part.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe the signature is valid?  You say you haven't checked it, and the error message says it's invalid. Or are you asking how to construct a valid signature?

Comment: Hi @SarahMesser, thank you for your reply. I have run the code and got that error message.

I follow the calculation for the signature on the documentation given but still get that error message. I'm asking if anyone knows which part of the code is wrong

Comment: The documentation you linked appears to require a login, which is going to make it difficult to help you.  My first guess is that you're using the wrong string for the `secret`, so check that.  However, your construction of the `factor` that forms the basis of your `signature` seems _highly_ _unusual_.  I suppose it's possible that's what is required by the spec, but AFAIK, `timestamp` and `payload` are not typical inclusions for most APIs.  Confirm they're supposed to be there and check the format that's expected for the timestamp.

Comment: thank for pointing it out. i almost forgot about appID and Secret

Comment: this is the calculation for signature from the doc

Authentication header structure
Authorization: SHA256 Credentials={Appid}, Timestamp={Timestamp}, Signature={Calculation method:SHA256(Credential+Timestamp+Payload+Secret}


Example Of Authorization Header
Authorization: SHA256 Credential=123456, Timestamp=1599999999, Signature=9bc0bd3ba6c41d98a591976bf95db97a58720a9e6d778845408765c3fafad69d.

Comment: here is the picture of the documentation https://ibb.co/q9JRB7h
https://ibb.co/th99m4F

Comment: The example shows `signature=sha256(factor)`, but your code has `signature = hashlib.sha256(factor.encode()).hexdigest()`.  Why are you doing it a different way?

Comment: @JohnGordon, I was doing it on python. The documentation is for general code. In python that is how you encode into sha256 using hashlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The documentation might be lack of info but this is how i construct my payload

```
payload = """
  {
  "query": "query Fetch($page:Int){
    productOfferV2(
      listType: 0, 
      sortType: 2,
      page: $page,
      limit: 50
    ) {
      nodes {
        commissionRate
        commission
        price
        productLink
        offerLink
      }
    }
  }",
  "operationName": null,
  "variables":{
    "page":0
    } 
  }
  """
  payload = payload.replace('\n','').replace(':0',f':{page}')
  timestamp = int(time.time())
  factor = appID+str(timestamp)+payload+secret
  signature = hashlib.sha256(factor.encode()).hexdigest()

  # Set the request headers
  headers = {
      'Content-type':'application/json',
      'Authorization':f'SHA256 Credential={appID},Timestamp={timestamp},Signature={signature}'
  }

  # Send the POST request
  response = requests.post(url,payload,headers=headers)

  data = response.json()
  return data['data']['productOfferV2']['nodes']
```

I hope this answer will help someone that facing the same issue